# C# expression - extract the string name (Deep)

Tags: c#, expression

I have the function bellow, returning "Test" when I call it `GetPropertyName<Model>(x => x.Test)`.
How can I return deep call eg: User.UserName.
I want to see `User.UserName` when I call it `GetPropertyName<Model>(x => x.User.FullName)`

Thanks

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (body == null)
    {
        body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    }
    if (body != null)
    {
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Edit 1**

this is my classes:

```
public class Place : BaseEntity
{
     public virtual User UserManager { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
     public virtual string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your code has something redundant, just this `if (body == null) {
        body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    } return body.Member.Name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method loops through the nodes in the expression, casts the node to a property and adds it to a list.

```
private IList<PropertyInfo> GetProperties<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> fullExpression)
{
    Expression expression;
    switch (fullExpression.Body.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
        case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
            var ue = fullExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
            expression = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
            break;
        default:
            expression = fullExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
            break;
    }

    var props = new List<PropertyInfo>();

    while(expression != null && expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        var memberExp = expression as MemberExpression;

        if(memberExp.Member is FieldInfo)
            throw InvalidExpressionException.FieldFound;

        var prop = memberExp.Member as PropertyInfo;
        props.Insert(0, prop);

        expression = memberExp.Expression;
    }
    return props;
}
```

If you then want to get a string like this: `User.UserName`, you can do it this way:

```
var props = GetProperties<Model>(m => m.User.Username);
var propNames = props.Select(p => p.Name);
string names = string.Join(".", propNames);
```

Comment: Thanks, but your method cannot be compiled. and this is my input: `Expression<Func<T, object>>` I dont think I can use: `Expression<T, TProp>`

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include `Func` in the signature.

Comment: Hi again... Sorry but I was mistake. inside your function `expression.NodeType` is Convert. can it be because the members are virtuals? Thanks

Comment: Whats the expression you're trying to pass?

Comment: "A cast or conversion operation, such as (SampleType)obj in C#" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179.aspx

Comment: `x => x.User.FullName` User and FullName are virtual. I am also passing x => x.Id (Id is virtual)

Comment: I think it may actually be because the func is `<T, object>`. Try changing that to `<T, TProp>` as I originally suggedted, and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Please see edit 1 in my post. and the virtual did not make the change

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't so easy (-: